# Detecting if another instance of the application is already running

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, mutex, multiple-instances

My application needs to behave slightly differently when it loads if there is already an instance running.

I understand how to use a mutex to prevent additional instances loading, but that doesn't quite solve my problem.

For example:

- Instance 1 loads, gets the mutex.
- Instance 2 loads, can't get the mutex, knows there's another instance.  So far, so good.
- Instance 1 closes, releases the mutex.
- Instance 3 loads, gets the mutex, doesn't know that Instance 2 is still running.

Any ideas?  Thankfully it doesn't need to deal with multiple user accounts or anything like that.

(C#, desktop application)

Edit: To clarify, the application doesn't need to be restricted to a single instance, just perform a slightly different start-up action if there's another instance already running.  Multiple instances are fine (and expected).

Comment: in the scenario you mentioned, whats the desired behavior? should instance 3 do what instance 1 was doing and instance 2 continue to  behave like before ?
(assuming you don't want to ensure single instance, since that is solved by the mutex. instance 2 will exit eventually anyway)

Comment: In this scenario, Instance 1 behaves one way, Instances 2 and 3 need to use the alternative behaviour.  If there is an instance already running, regardless of when it started or what's happened since, a new instance will behave slightly - though not signficantly - differently.  The difference is only a one-off action on loading.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will probably do just what you want. It has the nice additional feature of bringing the already running instance forward.

**EDIT:** updated the code to determine the application title automatically.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

static void Main()
{
    if (!EnsureSingleInstance())
    {
        return;
    }

    //...
}

static bool EnsureSingleInstance()
{
    Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

    var runningProcess = (from process in Process.GetProcesses()
                          where
                            process.Id != currentProcess.Id &&
                            process.ProcessName.Equals(
                              currentProcess.ProcessName,
                              StringComparison.Ordinal)
                          select process).FirstOrDefault();

    if (runningProcess != null)
    {
        ShowWindow(runningProcess.MainWindowHandle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
        SetForegroundWindow(runningProcess.MainWindowHandle);

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetForegroundWindow")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern Boolean ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);

private const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
```

Comment: I'd add that APPLICATION-TITLE is the executable filename without the extension (if I remember correctly).

Comment: @sztomi: thanks for sparking the memory of having code lying around for determining that automatically.

Comment: Haha, nice. I think I hardcoded it when I had this problem. This is much better :)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to detect the running instance as detailed in [Scott Hanselman's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=d2f676ea-025b-4fd6-ae79-80b04a34f24c)

His example activates the first instance when the second tries.

However, it wouldn't be hard to get the second instance to just stop if that's what you wanted.

Comment: Why won't anybody use the existing mechanism in [WindowsFormsApplicationBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.aspx)? Just because its namespace contains VisualBasic! If the authors had put it in a namespace Foo it would be used by much more people.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Semaphore instead of a Mutex

Answer (score 0):

Could you simply check `GetLastError()` after creating the mutex with `CreateMutex()`? If it returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, then there is another running instance of your application.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411%28VS.85%29.aspx,

> If the mutex is a named mutex and the
>   object existed before this function
>   call, the return value is a handle to
>   the existing object, GetLastError 
>   returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS,
>   bInitialOwner is ignored, and the
>   calling thread is not granted
>   ownership. However, if the caller has
>   limited access rights, the function
>   will fail with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED and
>   the caller should use the OpenMutex 
>   function.

**EDIT:** Just realized this was a C#/.Net question, sorry.

In .Net, use the Mutex constructor that returns the createdNew flag, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwe34f1k%28VS.80%29.aspx:

```
public Mutex (
    bool initiallyOwned,
    string name,
    out bool createdNew
)
```

Answer (score 0):

a good approach is to use the Sandor solution but use WMI to obtain the processes list, described here: [C#: How to get the full path of running process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497064/c-how-to-get-the-full-path-of-running-process) (Jeff's solution). that way, you can also check if the other running instances match by path and remote terminal session id:

```
    static bool EnsureSingleInstance()
    {
        Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

        var wmiQueryString = "SELECT ProcessId, ExecutablePath, CommandLine FROM Win32_Process";
        using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQueryString))
        using (var results = searcher.Get())
        {
            var query = from p in Process.GetProcesses()
                        join mo in results.Cast<ManagementObject>()
                        on p.Id equals (int)(uint)mo["ProcessId"]
                        select new
                        {
                            Process = p,
                            Path = (string)mo["ExecutablePath"],
                            CommandLine = (string)mo["CommandLine"],
                        };

            var runningProcess = (from process in query
                                  where
                                    process.Process.Id != currentProcess.Id &&
                                    process.Process.ProcessName.Equals(
                                      currentProcess.ProcessName,
                                      StringComparison.Ordinal) &&
                                      process.Path == currentProcess.MainModule.FileName &&
                                      process.Process.SessionId == currentProcess.SessionId
                                  select process).FirstOrDefault();

            return runningProcess == null;
        }
    }
```