# How to get the full path of running process?

Tags: c#

I am having an application that is changing some settings of another application (it is a simple C# application that run by double clicking (no setup required)).

After changing the settings I need to restart the other application so that it reflects the changed settings.

So to do, I have to kill the running process and start the process again, But the problem is after killing I am not able to find the process. (Reason is system do not know where the exe file is..)

**Is there any way to find out the path of running process or exe, if it is running?**

I do not want to give path manually, i.e. if it is running get the path, kill the process and start again else .... I will handle later

Answer (score 204, accepted):

```
 using System.Diagnostics;
 var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess(); // Or whatever method you are using
 string fullPath = process.MainModule.FileName;
 //fullPath has the path to exe.
```

There is one catch with this API, if you are running this code in 32 bit application, you'll not be able to access 64-bit application paths, so you'd have to compile and run you app as 64-bit application (Project Properties → Build → Platform Target → x64).

Comment: @GAPS: I'm sure he means, "get your process instance however you get it here."

Comment: @ jeff   ya me thinking same but at last `if you don't have` is also there

Comment: I was not sure on the mechanism you were getting your process object, so `GetProcessHowever()` is a place holder for that logic, and provided comment to get all processes and do some kind of selection if you want.

Comment: It gives problem Access is denied on line `string fullPath = process.Modules[0].FileName;` Any idea please?

Comment: Yes Sami you have edited the answer which includes the solution of your problem now... :D

Comment: Instead of changing Platform Target to x64, I changed Platform Target to Any and unchecked the **Prefer 32 bit** option

Comment: Doesn't work in Terminal Servers Sessions! --> Access Denied!

Comment: According to my measurements, calling `process.Modules[0]` is **50 times slower** than calling `process.MainModule`.

Comment: Is there any guarantee that the first module is the main module?

Comment: You should definitely be using `process.MainModule`, not `process.Modules[0]`.

Comment: Bad solution for "FreeBSD 10.2", not implemented.

Comment: see this link if you have an "acces denied" error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399819/access-denied-while-getting-process-path/3654195#3654195

Comment: I m not the path of specific file. it only gives path of exe

Comment: Please note that `Process.GetCurrentProcess()` returns an `IDisposable` and you should call it in a `using` block.

Comment: Still works well for WinUI packaged app.

Answer (score 119):

What you can do is use WMI to get the paths.  This will allow you to get the path regardless it's a 32-bit or 64-bit application.  Here's an example demonstrating how you can get it:

```
// include the namespace
using System.Management;

var wmiQueryString = "SELECT ProcessId, ExecutablePath, CommandLine FROM Win32_Process";
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQueryString))
using (var results = searcher.Get())
{
    var query = from p in Process.GetProcesses()
                join mo in results.Cast<ManagementObject>()
                on p.Id equals (int)(uint)mo["ProcessId"]
                select new
                {
                    Process = p,
                    Path = (string)mo["ExecutablePath"],
                    CommandLine = (string)mo["CommandLine"],
                };
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        // Do what you want with the Process, Path, and CommandLine
    }
}
```

Note that you'll have to reference the `System.Management.dll` assembly and use the `System.Management` namespace.

For more info on what other information you can grab out of these processes such as the command line used to start the program (`CommandLine`), see the [Win32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) class and [WMI .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404655.aspx) for for more information.

Comment: your answer is awesome, but my current app is small one... I keep this in mind

Comment: +1 perhaps for this question it's an overkill, but because of the 32/64bit independency, this method came in really handy when I wanted to get [64bit-process information from a running 32bit process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501771/how-to-avoid-a-win32-exception-when-accessing-process-mainmodule-filename-in-c).

Comment: Unlike the accepted Answer, this also works in Terminal Server Enviroments. Good job, helped me much!

Comment: Note that the `Path` property set from `mo["ExecutablePath"]` is `null` for some processes.

Comment: @Sam do you know why it is null? Trying the method above gives me 52 processes with not null, but `Process.GetProcesses().Length` is equal to 112.

Comment: @andreas, no; I don't know exactly why. It seems to be normal in Windows. Even if you open up Task Manager in Windows and look over the processes, you should see that only some of them have corresponding executables shown.

Comment: This solution seems to just filter out the non-Win32 processes in the GetProcesses() results. Yet, there does not appear to be an easy way to determine this important characteristic from the Process component itself. How frustrating. The use cases for this component (façade) must have been pretty narrow.

Comment: In case Visual Studio complains about missing references for `Process.GetProcesses()` and `results.Cast<>` you also need to add `using System.Linq` directive.

Answer (score 27):

### A solution for:

- **Both 32-bit AND 64-bit processes**
- **System.Diagnostics only** *(no System.Management)*

I used the [solution from Russell Gantman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46671939/5185376) and rewritten it as an extension method you can use like this:

```
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer").First();
string path = process.GetMainModuleFileName();
// C:\Windows\explorer.exe
```

With this implementation:

```
internal static class Extensions {
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool QueryFullProcessImageName([In] IntPtr hProcess, [In] uint dwFlags, [Out] StringBuilder lpExeName, [In, Out] ref uint lpdwSize);

    public static string GetMainModuleFileName(this Process process, int buffer = 1024) {
        var fileNameBuilder = new StringBuilder(buffer);
        uint bufferLength = (uint)fileNameBuilder.Capacity + 1;
        return QueryFullProcessImageName(process.Handle, 0, fileNameBuilder, ref bufferLength) ?
            fileNameBuilder.ToString() :
            null;
    }
}
```

Comment: QueryFullProcessImageName returns BOOL. We don't need to compare it with 0. https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.QueryFullProcessImageName

Comment: There is a permison problem: `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'Access is denied'`.

Answer (score 25):

I guess you already have the process object of the running process (e.g. by `GetProcessesByName()`).
You can then get the executable file name by using:

```
Process p;
string filename = p.MainModule.FileName;
```

Comment: if not use: var p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            string filename = p.MainModule.FileName;

Comment: The "A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process." limitation is unfortunately here too.

Answer (score 8):

By combining Sanjeevakumar Hiremath's and Jeff Mercado's answers you can actually in a way get around the problem when retrieving the icon from a 64-bit process in a 32-bit process.

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int processID = 6680;   // Change for the process you would like to use
            Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processID);
            string path = ProcessExecutablePath(process);
        }

        static private string ProcessExecutablePath(Process process)
        {
            try
            {
                return process.MainModule.FileName;
            }
            catch
            {
                string query = "SELECT ExecutablePath, ProcessID FROM Win32_Process";
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

                foreach (ManagementObject item in searcher.Get())
                {
                    object id = item["ProcessID"];
                    object path = item["ExecutablePath"];

                    if (path != null && id.ToString() == process.Id.ToString())
                    {
                        return path.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

This may be a bit slow and doesn't work on every process which lacks a "valid" icon.

Comment: This usage might be improved slightly with `string query = "SELECT ExecutablePath, ProcessID FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessID = " + process.Id;`... but this method is still quite slow, getting all the results and 'caching' them would be the best speed improvement, if you're getting the path of more than 1 process

Answer (score 8):

Here is a reliable solution that works with both **32bit** and **64bit** applications.

Add these references:

> using System.Diagnostics;
>
> using System.Management;

Add this method to your project:

```
public static string GetProcessPath(int processId)
{
    string MethodResult = "";
    try
    {
        string Query = "SELECT ExecutablePath FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " + processId;

        using (ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Query))
        {
            using (ManagementObjectCollection moc = mos.Get())
            {
                string ExecutablePath = (from mo in moc.Cast<ManagementObject>() select mo["ExecutablePath"]).First().ToString();

                MethodResult = ExecutablePath;

            }

        }

    }
    catch //(Exception ex)
    {
        //ex.HandleException();
    }
    return MethodResult;
}
```

Now use it like so:

```
int RootProcessId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;

GetProcessPath(RootProcessId);
```

Notice that if you know the id of the process, then this method will return the corresponding ExecutePath.

**Extra, for those interested:**

```
Process.GetProcesses()
```

...will give you an array of all the currently running processes, and...

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess()
```

...will give you the current process, along with their information e.g. Id, etc. and also limited control e.g. Kill, etc.*

Comment: I just get Access Denied

Comment: @Damien Have you tried running visual studio/your application with administrator privileges? Right click the program and select from the menu. Please let me know how you get on

Answer (score 4):

You can use pInvoke and a native call such as the following. This doesn't seem to have the 32 / 64 bit limitation (at least in my testing)

Here is the code

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
    static extern uint QueryFullProcessImageName(IntPtr hProcess, uint flags, StringBuilder text, out uint size);

    //Get the path to a process
    //proc = the process desired
    private string GetPathToApp (Process proc)
    {
        string pathToExe = string.Empty;

        if (null != proc)
        {
            uint nChars = 256;
            StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder((int)nChars);

            uint success = QueryFullProcessImageName(proc.Handle, 0, Buff, out nChars);

            if (0 != success)
            {
                pathToExe = Buff.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                pathToExe = ("Error = " + error + " when calling GetProcessImageFileName");
            }
        }

        return pathToExe;
    }
```

Comment: I just get Access Denied

Answer (score 2):

```
private void Test_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
   string path;
   path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase );
    Console.WriiteLine( path );  
}
```

Comment: @GAPS: this is for Executing Assembly (the which is currently running )

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Best Solution ever, because works even on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

ProcessModuleCollection modules = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Modules;
string processpathfilename;
string processmodulename;
if (modules.Count > 0) {
    processpathfilename = modules[0].FileName;
    processmodulename= modules[0].ModuleName;
} else {
    throw new ExecutionEngineException("Something critical occurred with the running process.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of .NET 6, you can use `Environment.ProcessPath`.

In a test, you can see that it gives the same result as `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName`:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    public static void printAllprocesses()
    {
        Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

        foreach (Process process in processlist)
        {
            try
            {
                String fileName = process.MainModule.FileName;
                String processName = process.ProcessName;

                Console.WriteLine("processName : {0},  fileName : {1}", processName, fileName);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                /* You will get access denied exception for system processes, We are skiping the system processes here */
            }

        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        printAllprocesses();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For others, if you want to find another process of the same executable, you can use:

```
public bool tryFindAnotherInstance(out Process process) {
    Process thisProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    string thisFilename = thisProcess.MainModule.FileName;
    int thisPId = thisProcess.Id;
    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        try
        {
            if (p.MainModule.FileName == thisFilename && thisPId != p.Id)
            {
                process = p;
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
    process = default;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to implement process query path using `PInvoke` on `OpenProcess`, `GetModuleFileNameEx`.

See full answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34991822/2338477).

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Management;
ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM 
Win32_Process");
        foreach (ManagementObject currentObj in search.Get())
        {
            if (currentObj["Caption"].ToString() == "sqlservr.exe")
            MessageBox.Show(currentObj["ExecutablePath"].ToString());
        }
```

Comment: How does this differ from the other answers using WMI?

Comment: @Klaus Gütter
Сompactness

Answer (score 0):

Hello I am not a great programmer, I am just learning by using small blocks of code. I needed to make a small program just to see the path for all running processes by combining WMI code I managed to get what I was looking for. May it will help who is starting with programming like me :) please don’t throw rocks at me :D
The main code was provided by Jeff Mercado

```
class Main
{
  foreach (var item in Process.GetProcesses())
  {

  var result = GetMainModuleFilepath(item.Id);
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(result + " " + item.Id);
  }

}

string GetMainModuleFilepath(int processId)
{
string wmiQueryString = "SELECT ProcessId, ExecutablePath FROM 
Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = " + processId;
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQueryString))
{
    using (var results = searcher.Get())
    {
        ManagementObject mo = results.Cast<ManagementObject> 
().FirstOrDefault();
        if (mo != null)
        {
            return (string)mo["ExecutablePath"];
        }
    }
}
return null;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The `Process` class has a member `StartInfo` that you should check out:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo_members(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: This only applies to local processes that were started using `Process.Start()`, not existing processes.

Comment: Exactly. It's rather "how to start the process" than "how this process started".

Answer (score -4):

I got to this thread while looking for the current directory of an executing process.  In .net 1.1 Microsoft introduced:

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

Seems to work well (but doesn't return the name of the process itself).

Comment: That'll only return the directory the executable is located in under some circumstances. You can, for instance, open a command line, change to any random directory, and run the executable by specifying a full path to it; GetCurrentDirectory() will return the directory you executed from rather than the executable's directory. From [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx): _"The current directory is distinct from the original directory, which is the one from which the process was started."_