# A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, winapi

I am trying to get the window under mouse, but, when I reach the code: Process.GetProcessById, I get this error:

```
A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process.
```

Here is my code:

```
NativeMethods.POINT p;

if (NativeMethods.GetCursorPos(out p))
            {

                IntPtr hWnd = NativeMethods.WindowFromPoint(p);
                NativeMethods.GetWindowModuleFileName(hWnd, fileName, 2000);

string WindowTitle= fileName.ToString().Split('\\')[fileName.ToString().Split('\\').Length - 1];
// WindowTitle will never change, it will get my window only!

            }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

static class NativeMethods
        {

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(POINT Point);

            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern uint GetWindowModuleFileName(IntPtr hwnd,
                StringBuilder lpszFileName, uint cchFileNameMax);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out NativeMethods.POINT lpPoint);


            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct POINT
            {
                public int X;
                public int Y;

                public POINT(int x, int y)
                {
                    this.X = x;
                    this.Y = y;
                }

                public static implicit operator System.Drawing.Point(POINT p)
                {
                    return new System.Drawing.Point(p.X, p.Y);
                }

                public static implicit operator POINT(System.Drawing.Point p)
                {
                    return new POINT(p.X, p.Y);
                }
            }

            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct RECT
            {
                public int Left;
                public int Top;
                public int Right;
                public int Bottom;
            }
        }
```

Here is my try to use invoke in WPF:

```
void dispatcherOp_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(
                new System.Threading.ThreadStart(
                  delegate()
                  {
                      System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation
                        dispatcherOp = this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        new Action(
                          delegate()
                          {
                              NativeMethods.POINT p;
                              if (NativeMethods.GetCursorPos(out p))
                              {
                                  IntPtr hWnd = NativeMethods.WindowFromPoint(p);
                                  NativeMethods.GetWindowModuleFileName(hWnd, fileName, 2000);

                                  uint processID = 0;
                                  uint threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out processID);
                                  string filename= Process.GetProcessById((int)processID).MainModule.FileName;
                              }

                          }
                      ));
                      dispatcherOp.Completed -= new EventHandler(dispatcherOp_Completed);
                      dispatcherOp.Completed += new EventHandler(dispatcherOp_Completed);
                  }
              ));


            thread.Start();
        }
```

Comment: Did you see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497064/c-how-to-get-the-full-path-of-running-process/5497319#5497319

Comment: You should try compiling your application using the "Any CPU" configuration.

Comment: Well, as the error says, you can't get the information through `Process.GetProcessById`. So, p/invoke the native methods to get what you need.

Comment: @David, I am already invoking it as you can see above

Comment: @spender, I will see that answer, thanks

Comment: No, you are calling `GetProcessById()` passing the ID of a 64 bit process.

Comment: So, the Process.GetProcessById shall be p/invoked? is there an easy way to so?

Comment: No, you cannot do that. That's the whole point of the question. You need to get hold of the file name some other way. It would appear that you cannot get a `Process` instance of a 64 bit process. AnyCPU would solve your problem. Can you do that?

Comment: AnyCPU is not allowed here in my team ..