# Kill a process that use a certain image path

Tags: c#

I need to find a way to kill all processes that use a certain image path. I have been finding that killing the process by name doesn't always kill the process properly - due to the fact that its developers are unable to keep the same name from build to build.

I have done some digging around, but haven't been able to find a solution to this. Wondering if someone here can point me in the right direction.

Comment: could you give us an example of an image path?

Comment: like C:\applicationfolder

Comment: Take a look at this code [C#: How to get the full path of running process?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497064/c-how-to-get-the-full-path-of-running-process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want

```
var imagePath = @"C:\applicationfolder";
var processes = Process.GetProcesses()
                .Where(p => p.MainModule.FileName.StartsWith(imagePath, true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
foreach (var proc in processes)
{
    proc.Kill();
}
```

Comment: ShaneSuperflyMacNeill, put your application in folder `C:\P` or `C:\W` and have fun :)

Comment: heh, I'm not arguing about best practices lol. Just doing what he wanted. Yes `C:\P` or `C:\W` would be quite humorous when everything just shuts down.

Comment: that worked perfectly. Although I am unsure what CultureInfo.InvariantCulture is, don't think I have used it before so MSDN will be my next stop :)

Comment: It's used to determine how the strings are compared by culture. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k0axhx9.aspx

Comment: well I have had to drop this as it gives an exception error "Unable to enumerate the process modules"
not sure how to fix that.

Comment: @I4V Just use a backslash at the end of the folder name and you do not have this problem -> C:\P\

Answer (score 3):

```
Process.GetProcesses()
        .First(p => String.Compare(p.MainModule.FileName,filename,true)==0)
        .Kill();
```

Comment: This throws "access denied" when it runs into system processes.

Comment: only if filename points to a systemprocess, but it will throw a NullReference Exception if there is no Process running with the specified filename

Answer (score 2):

this would kill all Processes that runs in the specific directory

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
.Where(p => Path.GetDirectoryName(p.MainModule.FileName).ToLower().Equals(path.ToLower())
.ToList().ForEach(p => p.Kill());
```

Comment: You're missing a bracket. `.Where(p => Path.GetDirectoryName(p.MainModule.FileName).ToLower().Equals(path.ToLower())**)**`