# how can i get fileversioninfo from 64 bits process C#

Tags: c#, process

I need to get the following information about `FileVersionInfo.FileDescription` and `FileVersionInfo.ProductName` for a 64-bit process, is this possible?

When is a 32-bit process I get this way, as if in this, but when is a 64-bit process could not get a way to get this information.

```
if (32BitProcess)
{
    descricaoArquivo = Process.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription;
    nomePrograma = Process.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.ProductName;
}
else
{
    nomePrograma = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
    descricaoArquivo = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName);
}
```

Comment: `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo` ?

Comment: Are you doing this from a 32 bit process?

Comment: sorry guys, i need to know some information about processes, such as MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription, but in 64-bit processes this information is null, I can just get them in 32-bit processes

Comment: yes, I'm doing this from a 32-bit process

Answer (score 2):

```
var versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(yourExePath);
string fileDescription = versionInfo.FileDescription;
string productName = versionInfo.ProductName;
```

Comment: Sure, but that means you have to know the exe path. Is there a way to get the exe path from a Process object that doesn't involve using a [ManagementObjectSearcher](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5497319/771768)?

Comment: @CarlWalsh `process.MainModule.FileName` is what you're asking for?

Comment: Thanks, but user3061673 was asking about getting the info of a 64-bit process from a 32-bit process. And the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainmodule(v=vs.110).aspx) specifically says that `MainModule` with throw if "A 32-bit process is trying to access the modules of a 64-bit process."