# T4 Get Execution File Name of Current Solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, t4, texttemplate

I'm using `T4` text template to generate a C# class for use in any c# projects.
But, now I need to know the target project execution file name, then to know that config file name and ...

For this job I tried to blow codes, but I think is not stable for all projects.

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="false" hostspecific="true" #>
<#@ assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

<# 
 IServiceProvider serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)this.Host;
 var dte = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;  
 var solutionsPath = Host.ResolveAssemblyReference("$(SolutionDir)"); 
 var projectItem = dte.Solution.FindProjectItem(Host.TemplateFile);
 var vsProject = projectItem.ContainingProject; 
#>

1.<#= System.IO.Path.GetFileName(dte.Solution.FullName) #>
2.<#= solutionsPath  #>
3.<#= this.Host.ResolveParameterValue("-", "-", "projects") #>
4.<#= dte.Solution.FullName #>
5.<#= vsProject.Name #>
```

Result is:

```
1.ProjectName.sln
2.D:\MyProject\SolutionDirectory\src\
3.ProjectName1|ProjectName2|ProjectName3
4.D:\MyProject\SolutionDirectory\src\ProjectName.sln
5.ProjectName
```

Please help me to find a stable and safe way to get current project execution file name, for example: `projectname.exe` or `$(TargetFileName)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497064/c-how-to-get-the-full-path-of-running-process

Comment: @Unlockedluca thanks, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497064/c-how-to-get-the-full-path-of-running-process) is for runtime projects not for T4 text template. and in T4 get this: `devenv.exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ProjectItem projItem = dte.Solution.FindProjectItem(Host.TemplateFile);
Project prj = projItem.ContainingProject;
string outputFileName = prj.Properties.Item("OutputFileName").Value.ToString();
```