# Kill process of a file listed in a listbox from a folder?

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that lists various files from a folder into a listbox control. That folder, which contains the files listed in the listbox, some of them are running on the computer but I want to delete all files available in that folder( and which are listed in the listbox). How can I firstly close the process or processes if more(but only if it they're running!), and after that, successfully delete that file or files. Do I need to get the process ID first ? (I don't want to close that process using the file name, because it is misleading, file names could be the same for more files and they're other files which I don't want to be deleted).

I have this to get process ID:

```
Dim aProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process
aProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(PID) 
aProcess.Kill()
```

** Not sure how to get the process ID from the file(s) listed on the listbox which are actually from a folder, so I may need to get the process ID from file path like ("C:\ProgramFiles\TestApp\Test.exe", not only "Test.exe")

If the file is not running, I am able to successfully delete the file from that specific folder, like this:

```
Try
    For Each z In Listbox1.Items
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(z) Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(z)
            Listbox1.Items.Remove(z)
            Msgbox("The files have been successfully deleted!")
        End If
    Next
Catch Ex As Exception
End Try
```

But the only trouble is the kill process part. If the process is running, the file , obviously cannot be deleted. It has to be done from the **full** file path, not only "filename.exe"

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the full path of running process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497064/how-to-get-the-full-path-of-running-process)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. First, that is C# version, I need VB.NET version. Also, even so, I looked up on it, it wouldn't help either. I know it is something related to API architecture, but not sure how to do that. If I do it using only filename "test.exe" I am able to close it, but IF there are more "test.exe" files running on the PC(and which are NOT in that folder), I don't want to close those, but the only 'filename' method also closes those. I want to close process using full path. I already have those files listed in listbox with the full path.

Comment: So, store in your ListBox the full path of the executables you listed from that source Directory. What problem do you have with that?

Comment: I am able to successfully store the files from that folder in the listbox. I am unable to KILL the process IF a file is running from that folder?

Comment: The "Does this answer your question?" line is generated automatically by this website. It was not really a question of whether it answers your question because I know that it does. It does not matter whether you call the .NET methods from VB or C#, they are the same methods that are called the same way. [continued]

Comment: The C# question tells you how to get the full path of a certain `Process` object. You know how to [get all `Process` objects with a certain exe name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname?view=netcore-3.1#System_Diagnostics_Process_GetProcessesByName_System_String_). So you can filter the result of the latter to only keep those text.exe `Process` objects that also have the correct full path. [continued]

Comment: Alternatively, you can scroll to the [next answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5497319/11683) and use the WMI query, in the exactly same way, and add `where ExecutablePath = 'C:\ProgramFiles\TestApp\Test.exe'` to the `select` query.

Comment: And how do I KILL a certain process once I have the files listed in the listbox with their full paths? I don't seem to find any answers on this. I already have the full path of the files listed in the listbox, I do need something else, the kill process from full path.

Comment: GSerg already explained the whole process. You have the path of an executable (don't call it *file*). Search for a Process that has a corresponding `MainModule.FileName`. You can find it using `Process.GetProcesses()` or using a WMI query (which requires admin privileges, though). Or Win32 functions (really not necessary here). Note that some Processes can throw when you try to read their `MainModule` property, so try/catch that code.

Comment: You can write something like: `using (var proc = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id > 4 && p.MainModule.FileName == [Your ListBox Item])) { if (proc != null) { proc.Kill(); } }`

Comment: *that is C# version, I need VB.NET version* - you are aware that the two languages are the same thing, right?

Comment: `Using proc As Process = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.Id > 4 AndAlso p.MainModule.FileName = "[Your ListBox Item]") If proc IsNot Nothing Then proc.Kill() End Using`

Comment: I've added it like that:      Using proc As Process = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.Id > 4 AndAlso
                            p.MainModule.FileName = Listbox2.SelectedItem.ToString)
                        If proc IsNot Nothing Then
                            proc.Kill()
                        End If
                    End Using         * and I've tested it, I selected an item from Listbox2, but file is still running..

Comment: Error as follows: 'A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process.' Also, after disabling "Prefer 32-bit "from "Compile" settings, retrieved "Access is denied."

Comment: No further reply/help ?