# Process MainModule - can I avoid Win32 exception?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, winapi, win32exception

I am enumerating processes to find if `excel.exe` is running (for example).
I get a lot of `Win32Exception` from system services and such.

```
Process[] pps = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (var process in pps)
{
    string module = null;
    try
    {
        module = process.MainModule?.FileName;
    }
    catch (Win32Exception)
    {
        continue;
    }
```

which make enumeration to run 500ms instead of 10ms.

**Is there a way to figure if a process has main module without triggering the exception? Or any other way to find process exe path?**

Comment: I'm not sure, if `Process.GetProcessesByName("excel")` would perform better. Do you get that 500 ms delay also without debugging?

Comment: haha ! you got me.. I thought I did and I looked again just now and it was debug build I ran.. indeed it is down to 55ms.. Not 10 but still twice better than WMI. Thank you for pushing me :)

Comment: FYI - GetProcessByName is 40ms vs 50ms which is not bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception occurs when you're trying to do something which your OS doesn't allow. You can check the `NativeErrorCode` property to see more details about the exception.

You can find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5497319/6527049) to deal with that issue.

As mentioned by @steeeve in comment, you can use `GetProcessByName`, if performance is the only criteria for you.

Comment: WMI is 50 times slower IF there are no W32 errors. mismatch is nothing to do with it. Win32 is generic name of API and not bitness. Native error is -2147467259 which is `access denied` (although I run the app as administrator). nonetheless - I am asking if it is possible to avoid exceptions - as processing takes extra 500ms.. not examining what they are - dont care really..

Comment: "*I am asking if it is possible to avoid exceptions*" - you would have to use the relevant Win32 API functions directly, ie via PInvoke, rather than using the .NET wrapper classes. The wrapper source code is [available online](https://referencesource.microsoft.com), so you can see what the underlying API calls look like, and then make those same calls in your own code, just with different error handling that doesn't throw exceptions.

Comment: @BoppityBop please use `GetProcessByName` then

Comment: if you remove mentioning of bitness mismatch from your answer i can accept it. (btw i dont think "you can't access a 64-bit application's path from a 32-bit application" is true. i am not loading any dlls into 32 bit process I am just examining properties of an object which only describes a process not represents its code in any way, and my code in question runs as 64bit anyway)